# multiply definition of »main« won't compile

Tags: c

For my following code:

```
/* Comment */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

   printf("Hello World\n");

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I receive the following error message after trying to compile it:

```
/tmp/ccWMTR28.o: In Function »main«:
a2.c:(.text+0x0): multiply definition of »main«
/tmp/ccsLpnIP.o:a2.c:(.text+0x0): first here defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I type

```
gcc /Documents a2.c -Wall -Werror -std=c99 a2.c -o a2
```

to compile the file. I didn't link it with another .c file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error is not in the code you show us. How do you compile and link your code? Do you link together with another file containing `main`?

Comment: Hello, sorry i'm complete new into coding. I type gcc /Documents a2.c to search for the file, and then -Wall -Werror -std=c99 a2.c -o a2 to compile the file. I didn't link it with another .c file. Sorry for my bad explanation, im not very good at english and coding.

Comment: What do you mean with "to search for the file"? Please provide the full command line.

Comment: With "to search for the file" i mean to link the file so it can be found by the compiler, or is that wrong? The full command i type is: gcc /Documents a2.c -Wall -Werror -std=c99 a2.c -o a2

Comment: You are specifying a2.c twice on the command line, drop one of it

Comment: You do not search for anything. You just have to provide the file name to your compiler. In your case you provide same name twice.

Answer (score 4):

With your command line you provide same source file twice.
This results in 2 temporary files compiled from `a2.c`.
It the linker tries to include both `.o` files, and all the symbols in the file are duplicated.

Simply change your command line to this:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 a2.c -o a2
```

Comment: I tried it out now, the error message doesn't appear anymore, thank you. But shouldn't there appear something like "Hello World" or something on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, if you run your program after compilation, there should be some output. What happens when you run it?

Comment: How do i run it? Do i have to use a command? Sorry for being so dumb, it's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: You need to run the program. Compiling it is not enough. Once you have compiled it with `gcc ...`, runit with `./a2`.

Comment: Ohhhh it worked now. Thank you everyone, you really helped me out here!!

Comment: @Nic You're missing very basic knowledge, google "compile run program c linux", this should get you to some more information

Comment: Compiling a program is a bit like building a drill. Afterwards you have a tool but using it to drill a hole is another step

Comment: I will, thank you. And also thanks to Gerhardh and Ctx and everyone else.